# Ошибка CSRF токена, после входа в систему

Tags: python, django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

> Есть запрос на react
> `react.js`

```
function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = cookies[i].trim()
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}

axios.post('/api/registration', {
    'username': login,
    'email': email,
    'password': password,
    'X-CSRFToken': 'csrftoken',
})
```

> Есть APIView в python

```
class RegistrationView(APIView):
    serializer_class = RegistrationSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        username = request.data['username']
        email = request.data['email']
        password = make_password(request.data['password'])
        код...
        return Response('success')
```

При отправке запроса когда Пользователь НЕ авторизован, все отлично срабатывает, но когда авторизован, то есть я выполнил логин - пишет "CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing."...
В дефолтном интерфейсе DRF тоже нет ошибок.
Как достать нужный токен, или как решить эту ошибку, чтобы после входе в систему мог делать POST запросы?

[image: Пункт по этому поводу]

> Есть пункт по этому поводу в  Django документации, но не знаю как это исправить...

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=csrf+django , https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=csrf+react и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: это я хорошо посмотрел, там решают ошибку просто CSRF, у меня тоже все хорошо работает если не выполнен вход...
прошу читать внимательно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто все кроме логина и регистрации сделал методом GET вместо POST и не парился